# Where is the custody with lightning node?

Tags: lightning-network

I wrapped my head about LN a bit with LND and voltage ressources but regarding the custody I don't really get it. With bitcoin it's stateless as one can have the utxo's key and sign offline and just broadcast it to any node and any indexing node can query utxo's.

- What caveats should one be aware regarding LN custody ?
- Does a LN's node is design to be 1 to 1 with a user or 1 to N users ? How does this materialize ?
- When you interact with a node, it feels like the invoice "generated" is pegged to the node's default wallet (as if you create a bitcoin address from bitcoin-gui). Would it be possible to import N public addresses (1 for each different user) and generate an invoice with this specific anchor ? Or simply generate an invoice with a particular public address ?
- Does the one having control over a LN has access to the fund ?